# Anybody use resque gem with plugin resque-history and ActiveJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, rails-activejob

I use resque-history plugin for monitoring done tasks.

Firstly I include this string ***require 'resque-history/server'*** into routes file, and then I see new history tab in dashboard.

This is some code in ***/app/jobs/welcome_email_job.rb***

```
require 'resque-history'

class WelcomeEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  extend Resque::Plugins::History
  @max_history = 200
  @queue = :email

  def perform(user)
   UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver_now
    puts "I delivered mail to #{user.login} now, sincerly yours Resque <3"
  end
end
```

When job was done, I see in stats tab how many jobs was processed, but history tab empty, just only table head. Can I resolve this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your workers (they aren't restarted automatically).